# Problema con cuadro de texto más lista desplegable HTML

Tags: php, sql, html5, ajax

Estoy intentando realizar el típico campo de búsqueda que tienen los navegadores donde tú escribes y mientras vas escribiendo, te va mostrando sugerencias en una especie de lista desplegable.

El caso es que quiero que al escribir un nombre en el cuadro de texto me vaya autocompletando el nombre, por ejemplo si busco "jos" que me devuelva todas las personas que tienen esa cadena en su nombre y los muestre en una lista desplegable para que al hacerle click encima del nombre me lo ponga entero en el cuadro de texto.

He visto la funcion keyup para que cuando dejes de pulsar una tecla ejecute "X" cosa.

Os dejo mi código sobre el `keyup()` y mi campo de texto para que veáis como lo tengo hecho.

P.D: No es preciso que lo muestre en una lista desplegable con que me mostrará el 1 de la lista dentro del campo de texto (como en el autocompletar de los formularios) me bastaría.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#adm").on("keyup", function() {
        var cadena = $("#adm").val();
        <?php
        $ms->exe("select top 1 a_nom, a_id from fadm where a_nom like '%".$cadena."%';");
        echo $ms->field(null, 'a_nom'), $ms->field(null,'a_id');
        ?>
    });
  });

<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="adm" id="adm">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="adm">Administrador</label>
</div>
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar alguna libreria para lo que queres realizar.

La primera que se me viene a la mente es [Typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) de Twitter.

Hace exactamente lo que pedis y queda super linda!

Espero haberte ayudado. Abrazo!

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda era lo que estaba buscando. :D

Comment: Revisar [answer], en particular lo indicado para los enlaces.